# Symfony 2: How to generate image paths in javascript file?

Tags: symfony, assets

I've been googling this for long time! I need to show images on some menu hover and mouseout. The code is written in a js file. But the images path needs to be generated. Is there any way to generate image paths using something like this

{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/images/menu_down.png') }}

Can FOSJsRoutingBundle used to generate image paths in js files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agree with **Nick** answer, but he forgot the "quotes" around the {{ asset(...) }}.

So it should be written like this:

```
 var menuDownUrl = "{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/images/menu_down.png') }}";
```

if you want `window.menuDownUrl` to work and not output you **`"undefined"`**

Answer (score 13):

You could set global JS variables on your actual page:

```
<script>
    var menuDownUrl = "{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/images/menu_down.png') }}";
</script>
```

And then set inside your javascript file to call the global variable: `window.menuDownUrl`

Then creates a dependency inside your javascript file, but allows you to set that image dynamically.

Comment: I think twig functions are not recognized in a javascript file. I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Hey it actually worked. I had to put the code in my script block in my twig template. Thank You!!

Answer (score 8):

You can put an input hidden and set the path of the image.

```
<input type="hidden" id="img_path" value="{{ asset('images/circle_loading.gif') }}">
```

After that in jQuery you can use it like this

```
var img  = "<img src=\'"+ $("#img_path").val() +"\'>";
$("div").html(img);
```